# Change /SitePages/Home.aspx URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, url-rewriting, url-length

I have would like to have the url as short as possible on a modern SharePoint environment. As such, I created the site "z". However, then the Home page would become

```
https://domain.com/sites/z/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

Now I also want to make this shorter. So I changed the Site Page library to "z", expecting the URL to become

```
https://domain.com/sites/z/z/Home.aspx
```

However, this does not seem the work when you change the name of the library it keeps being https://.com/sites/z/SitePages/Home.aspx

Can this be done differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the Site Pages URL via PowerShell.

`Note:` Once modified, you will not be able to access the url of the original site (https://domain.com/sites/z ), you can only access it through the new url (https://domain.com/sites/z/z/Home.aspx).

**Please run the below PnP PowerShell as an admin:**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"
$LibName = "SitePages"
$NewLibURL = "z"
  
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Get the List
$Lib= Get-PnPList -Identity $LibName -Includes RootFolder
 
#sharepoint online powershell change list url
$Lib.Rootfolder.MoveTo($NewLibURL)

Invoke-PnPQuery
```

**Here is my test:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For future reference, remark, the news on the site will also not work anymore.